# Como almacenar la suma de los valores que se van ingresando en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen día! Les comento: Tengo una tabla llamada "productos" y quiero sumar los valores que se van ingresando en "$cantidad" en una columna que se llama "$total". Esto para poder llevar un registro del stock disponible. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function agregar_total($id_producto,$nombre,$cantidad){
global $con;    
$update=mysqli_query($con,"update productos set total=total+'$cantidad' where id_producto='$id_producto'");
```

Por algún motivo me esta actualizando todos los datos de la columna "total" y no solo la ultima fila. Ademas de esto realiza la suma en orden inverso, osea que suma de mayor a menor id. Por lo que el primer producto que ingreso queda con mas stock que el ultimo que he ingresado. 
Espero que puedan echarme una mano. Cualquier cosa quedo a su disposición si es que me ha faltado algún dato importante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que cogiese solo la ultima fila y con orden normal o ascendentela consulta sería:

```
$update=mysqli_query($con,"update productos set total=total+'$cantidad' 
where id_producto='$id_producto' order by id_producto asc limit 1");
```

Esto te lo ordena de menor a mayor por id y te coge solo el primero con el `limit`.

Comment: Excelente!! gracias por la ayuda.